# Hibernate - function rand() in MYSQLDialect

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I noticed that the MYSQLDialect defines `rand()` function as:

```
registerFunction("rand", new NoArgSQLFunction("rand", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE));
```

But, mysql allows use this function with argument (seed). [[approve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)]

I have extended MySQLDialect and redefined this function and my code works correctly now. Nonetheless i want to know - this is bug or feature? Should i create an issue in hibernate bug tracker?

hibernate version: 4.3.6.Final

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is bug.. I found the open issue in hibernate bug tracker.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3777